# Bitcoin-qt runs client correctly, but bitcoind downloads new software

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, client

I'm really struggling. I'm a bit new, but I'm trying to run bitcoind. When I run bitcoin-qt, everything is fine, but when I try to run bitcoind, it starts to download a new bitcoin core software. Does anyone know why this may be?

Thanks :)

Comment: How can you tell it's downloading new software? Do you have any logs you can share?

Comment: So, I know it because I am using a raspberry pi4. I mounted a 1tb SSD on the raspberry and the bitcoin-qt runs as intended on it. It has done it over several days. Once I run the bitcoind command from the same directory, it starts to download a new bitcoin core folder with the corresponding files directly on the raspberry 28gb ssd.

Comment: So sorry to bother you guys. I just figured it out, but I used many hours on this hehe. It was just some basic stuff with doing alias on bitcoind directory and bitcoin-cli. Thanks Vojtech!

Comment: No worries, glad you've figured it out!